# Update term_id to new value wherever it exists, to combine the two.

Tags: terms

We have two categories in our database, and the second one was created mistakenly and misspelled. The first is spelled correctly (term_id 43), and the second is not (term_id 86). I want to combine the two and delete the incorrect one.

I need to find all of the places where term_id=86 and update it to 43, then remove 86 from the wpjd_terms table. Problem is, I am not sure where to find this value in the various tables.

I'm new to WP database structure, familiar with using SQL. I'm looking at all of this through PHPMyAdmin. Would appreciate any help to make sure I don't break something as I fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE `wpjd_term_relationships` SET `term_taxonomy_id` = '43' WHERE `wpjd_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` = 86;

This did the trick.